# Using Delphi to read emails subfolders in InBox on Thunderbird

Tags: delphi

I need to read emails from Thunderbird email client for all accounts Inbox and all his subfolders.

How I change the code to read all email from every subfolders?

Thanks

With this code (get from examples by Jedy libraries) I read emails only from default InBox Folder:

```
DownloadsListView.Items.Clear;
JvMail1.LogonOptions := [JvMail.loNewSession, JvMail.loDownloadMail];
JvMail1.LogOn;
try
  b := JvMail1.FindFirstMail;
  while b do
  begin
    JvMail1.ReadOptions := [roFifo, roHeaderOnly, roPeek];
    JvMail1.ReadMail;
    with DownloadsListView.Items.Add do
    begin
      Caption := JvMail1.Subject;
      SubItems.Add(JvMail1.ReadedMail.RecipientName);
      SubItems.Add(DateTimeToStr(JvMail1.ReadedMail.DateReceived));
    end;
    b := JvMail1.FindNextMail;
  end;
finally
  JvMail1.LogOff;
  JvMail1.Clear;
  DownloadsListView.BringToFront;
end;
```

Comment: You may be interested in this component to read Thunderbird files:

`MiTeC Thunderbird Reader` (https://www.mitec.cz/mt.html)

Answer (score 2):

[`TJvMail`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvMail) is a wrapper for SimpleMAPI, which has no concept of subfolders, and can only access a profile's inbox. You would need to use CDO or Extended MAPI to have full access to a profile's subfolders, but `TJvMail` does not support that.

[Differences between CDO, Simple MAPI, and Extended MAPI](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/200018/differences-between-cdo-simple-mapi-and-extended-mapi)

Alternatively, use the IMAP protocol (such as via Indy's `TIdIMAP4` component) to access the email server directly, instead of accessing the user's local email client.